# The type is defined in an assembly that is not referenced when using a helper method

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I installed the Nuget packages X.PagedList and X.PagedList.Mvc and now when I call the Html Helper 'PagedListPager' I get this error message and the helper method has a red underline under it that says. The application builds with no errors and I can run the page no problem, but this red line in annoying!

> The type 'IEnumerable<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.  2_Views_Home_Events.cshtml

Question - does system.runtime version 4.0.0 have anything to do with the .net version the project is using? because I also upgraded .Net to 4.62 from 4.5.2 to get X.PagedList.Mvc to work correctly.

I followed the error message and tried adding the namespace to the view like this below but it didn't do anything. I also went to the references and right clicked to add a reference and looked through the list for System.Runtime, but I don't see any. I only see System, System.Runtime.* I don't see System.Runtime

Also I looked under the nuget package manager and see I can download the nuget package System.Runtime v4.3.0! Why isn't this included in the project to begin with? And will v4.3.0 work if it needs v4.0.0?

Win 10 with Visual Studio 2017 RC

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

OK this seems really stupid. System.Runtime doesn't come installed when you run VS and create a ASP.Net MVC project!! So I installed the nuget package System.Runtime to get it. Solved! Why wasn't it there to begin with? Looking at some quick details it looks like it contains types that are fundamental to programming like char, byte, string, etc, etc

Comment: If you found the answer to your own problem and are not looking for further answers, please mark this as the accepted answer